# How to insert spinBox in TableWidget's cell in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Show me, please, by example how should I do it. I'm newbie in Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)

> **void QTableWidget::setCellWidget(int row, int column, QWidget *
>   widget)**
>
> Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell in the given row and
>   column, passing the ownership of the widget to the table.
>
> If cell widget A is replaced with cell widget B, cell widget A will be
>   deleted. For example, in the code snippet below, the QLineEdit object
>   will be deleted.

Example:

```
tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col, new QSpinBox);
```